# Access to headers in request-promise get response

Tags: javascript, promise

I am complete newbie to JS world. I am trying to write a test case that tests user's actions on a site. I am using request-promise module to test the asyn calls.  I could not find any api documentation for request-promise. 
How do I get access to status code of the response? Right now it prints undefined. Also, can anyone please confirm, how do we know what promise returns when it is successful, is it  a single value that it resolves to or all the parameters that the async function returns. How do we know what are the parameters to function() in `request.get(base_url).then(function(response, body)`.

```
var request = require("request-promise");
var promise = require("bluebird");
//
var base_url = "https://mysignin.com/"
//
describe("My first test", function() {
 it("User is on the sign in page", function(done) {
    request.get(base_url).then(function(response, body){
     // expect(response.statusCode).toBe('GET /200');
      console.log("respnse " + response.statusCode);
      console.log("Body " + body);
      done();
    }).catch(function(error) {
        done("Oops somthing went wrong!!");
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: As I can see here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) clearly the first and the only parameter to then's function param is the body of the request as string.

Comment: And here it shows how to get the full response. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise#get-the-full-response-instead-of-just-the-body

Answer (score 50):

By default, the request-promise library returns only the response itself.  You can, however, pass a simple transform function in your options, which takes three parameters and allows you to return additional stuff.

So if I wanted the headers plus the response returned to me, I would just do this:

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var uri = 'http://domain.name/';

var _include_headers = function(body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) {
  return {'headers': response.headers, 'data': body};
};

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: uri,
  json: true,
  transform: _include_headers,
}

return request(options)
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.headers);
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

Answer (score 36):

By default `request-promise` returns just the response body from a request. To get the full response object, you can set `resolveWithFulLResponse: true` in the options object when making the request. [Example in the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise#get-the-full-response-instead-of-just-the-body)

```
var request = require('request-promise');

request.get('someUrl').then(function(body) {
  // body is html or json or whatever the server responds
});

request({
  uri: 'someUrl',
  method: 'GET',
  resolveWithFullResponse: true
}).then(function(response) {
  // now you got the full response with codes etc...
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Just passing  `resolveWithFullResponse: true` with in the get options should fetch the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Tsalikidis answer is correct. 
As for:

> Also, can anyone please confirm, how do we know what promise returns
>   when it is successful, is it a single value that it resolves to or all
>   the parameters that the async function returns

A promise (Promise/A+ compliant) always return one single value. Of course this value can be a deeply nested object with tons of information in it. But `.then(function(response,body){` is inherently wrong.

A library that sends back a promise should document the format of the returned object.