# Using a lambda API as a reverse proxy for content stored in S3?

Tags: aws-lambda

I would like to apply a reverse proxy on top of S3 to make content serving decisions based on the incoming request.

The S3 bucket is set to website mode and hosted publically.

I'll obviously have more logic to determine where I am getting the files from, but hopefully this will illustrate my desire.

This is using JavaScript, happy to use Go as well.

The following code does not work, but I'm not sure how best to get it working. Can I just send an arrayBuffer through?

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const data = await fetch(S3WebsiteURL + event.path)
  const buffer = await data.arrayBuffer()

  return {
    headers: data.headers,
    body: buffer,
    statusCode: 200
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

const htmlString = await rp(S3WebsiteURL + event.path);

return {
    body: htmlString,
    statusCode: 200
}
```

Try without headers and if it works, add [header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42543323/290036) support.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the file could be anything. Image, icon, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it difficult to use Lambda to proxy data - using API gateway, at least, it expects binary data in base-64 format at various points depending on how you set it up. They've improved things since I tried to do it that way last, so hopefully someone else can answer based on more recent experience.

If your content serving decisions are limited to access control (you don't need to transform the data you're serving), then you can use your lambda as a URL provider instead of a content provider - switch public sharing of the S3 bucket off, access the items using the S3 API, and have your lambda call `S3.getSignedUrl()` to get a link to the actual content. This means that only the callers of the lambda will have a valid URL to the content you want to protect, and depending on your application you can set the timeout on the pre-signed URL to be short enough you don't have to worry about it being shared.

The advantage here is that since the content itself doesn't get proxied through the lambda, your lambda runtime and memory costs can be lower and performance should be better.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const path = event.path === '/' ? 'index.html' : event.path.substring(1);
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'your-s3-bucket-name',
        Key: path,
    };
    
    try {
        const s3Object = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' },
            body: s3Object.Body.toString('utf-8'),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify(error),
        };
    }
};
```

This worked for me when serving react files. Does not however work with react-router-dom which is a shame.